# Adding a default value to selected list Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I am populating a dropdown like this

```
 primaryDrop = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"1", "Getting ready"}, 
                {"2", "Starting"}, 
                {"3", "All"}, 
                {"4", "Other"}

            };
        PrimaryDrop = primaryDrop.Select(item => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = item.Key,
            Text = item.Value
        });
```

And displaying it like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPrimary, new SelectList(Model.PrimaryDrop, "Value", "Text"), "Select ...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

How can I select a default value to 'Other' for example

Was thinking something like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPrimary, new SelectList(Model.PrimaryDrop, "Value", "Text", new { SelectedItem = "Other" }), "Select ...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create an object to specify the selected item, you just need to give the *value* you want. In your case, `Other` has a value of `4`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPrimary, 
                      new SelectList(ViewBag.PrimaryDrop, "Value", "Text", "4"),
                      "Select ...", 
                      new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by server code, when you populate data

```
PrimaryDrop = primaryDrop.Select(item => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = item.Key,
        Text = item.Value,
        Selected = item.Key == "4" // Or item.Value== "Others"  
    });
```

Or we can set value for SelectedPrimary of model

```
SelectedPrimary = "4"
```